# Basic question about inferior limit for a function

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to figure out the following detail from the proof of a proposition. But It's been a while since I've worked with inferior limits:

> Let $E$ be a topological space, $a \in E$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,
> and $f:E \rightarrow \tilde{\mathbb{R}}$ a function. If there exists a
> neighborhood $V$ of $a$ such that
>
> $$\lambda \leq \tilde{f(V)},$$
>
> then
>
> $$\lambda \leq \varliminf_{x \to a} f(x).$$

Could you give me an idea?

Comment: What is $f_n{}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I mean $f$. Fixed it!

Comment: And what is $\displaystyle\varliminf_{n \to \infty} f(x)$? There is no $n$ in $f(x)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You're right. I fix it as well.

Comment: What do all these $\tilde{}$s floating around mean?

Comment: @RobArthan The last one means closure, and the first one means that f is into the extended real line.